# jQuery saving data in array on click?

Tags: ajax, arrays, jquery, multidimensional-array

I wanted to save data in an array (or whatever best method) using jquery based on clicks. I have set up jquery where user can only click 2 elements (`<div>` tags), and if they wanted to select something else, they would need to unselect one of their selected elements. These elements has 'data-id=' within the  tag where I'm trying to store.

How do I save the data-id for only items that were selected. Does that mean the data in the array (or which best method is preferred) needs to be deleted if the user unselects?

```
$('.media-search').hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var dataid = $this.data('id');
    $this.toggleClass('highlight');
}).click(function(){
if($('.selectMedia').length < 2 || $(this).hasClass('selectMedia'))
{
    $(this).toggleClass('selectMedia');
}else{

    alert('need to unselect item')      

}
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: declared `var dataid` inside function goes away on focus lost...just saying

Comment: jQuery 1.9 removes depricated .hover event see blog here:http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/01/8-methods-that-will-not-work-in-jquery.html?goback=%2Eanp_100943_1358343060895_1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're asking for, but if you need an array, you can use this function at any point you want and store it in a variable:

```
function getArray() {
    var data = [],
        media = $('.selectMedia');

    for(var i = 0; i < media.length; i++) {
        data[i] = media.eq(i).attr("data-id");
    }

    return data;
}
```

My suggestion would be to use this function in the `click` function **after** you toggle the class.

Also, I noticed that you declare `dataid` inside the `hover` method, and that variable will cease to exist outside of the method, i.e. once you finish hovering, that value is now out of scope. So, if you do declare an array to store the result of this method in, do it **outside** of any of the event handlers so that it will remain in scope.

Answer (score 0):

I dont sure that i understand you but my solution is

```
var dataIds = new Array();

$('.media-search').click(function(){
 if($(this).hasClass('selectMedia')){
  $(this).removeClass('selectMedia');
  dataIds.splice(dataIds.indexOf($this.data('id')),1); 
 }else{
  if(dataIds.leght==2){
   $(this).addClass('selectMedia');
   dataIds.push($this.data('id'));
  }else{
   alert("only 2 items");
  }
 }
}
```